# virtual box cannot detect webcam in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, virtualbox, webcam, wine, acer-aspire

I have installed virtual box for ubuntu 9.10. I installed a windows xp inside it. And I don't know why it does not make the webcam available for the yahoo messenger installed in xp.
When I click on the device in the interface of virtual box. I can see the webcam but it is grayed out. And I don't know why. It is also not available when I use wine to execute yahoo messenger. 
And I know that it is working because I can see its working when I use skype for ubuntu.
Any suggestions?Its an acer aspire laptop, the webcam is built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have already installed the guest additions? If no, I suggest to do it now; if yes, did you tried to search and install a specific driver for the integrated webcam within windows?

Comment: yes it has guest additions installed. But it was installed while I was using windows. I just installed the vm as existing hard disk(.vdi). So maybe I'll try to search for it.